# Multiple Linear Reg-Applying Polynomial Terms to Interaction Effects

Tags: r, regression

I've been wracking my brains over this and cannot figure out what the best method to go about this is.

So far, I conducted my initial MLR

```
reg=lm(register~.,data=train)
```

From there, I checked for interaction effects using

```
testinter=glm(register~(.-atemp)*(.-atemp),data=train)
```

After Determining the Significant Interactions, I included all in my model.

```
reg=lm(register~season:month+season:temp+year:month+
     year:weekday+year:temp+month:temp+holiday:windspeed+weekday:
     weathersit+weekday:hum+weathersit:hum+
     hum+weathersit+season+year+temp, data=train)
```

However, after looking at some of the variables, hum and temp needed to be transformed to polynomial terms. hum^2 and temp^3.

My question is how can I include these in the interaction effects? 
This is my attempt so far, where I switched out "hum" with poly(hum,2,raw=T) but Im not sure if its correct.

```
reg=lm(register~season:month+season:poly(temp,3,raw=T)+year:month+
     year:weekday+year:poly(temp,3,raw=T)+month:poly(temp,3,raw=T)+holiday:windspeed+weekday:
     weathersit+weekday:poly(hum,2,raw=T)+weathersit:poly(hum,2,raw=T)+
     poly(hum,2,raw=T)+weathersit+season+year+poly(temp,3,raw=T), data=train)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that SO in general requires reproducible examples and the `r` tag specifically requests that you share the data via `dput()` if your example doesn't use builtin data. Please hover your mouse over the R tag for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `I()` when you need to do a transformation within an `lm` or `glm` equation.

Here's an example using the `iris` dataset:

```
data(iris)
reg <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width:I(Petal.Length^2), data=iris)
summary(reg)
```

> ```
> Call:
> lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width:I(Petal.Length^2), data = iris)
>
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -0.9405 -0.2357  0.0029  0.2224  0.8241 
>
> Coefficients:
>                                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)                   4.8649126  0.0478357  101.70   <2e-16 ***
> Sepal.Width:I(Petal.Length^2) 0.0192699  0.0007492   25.72   <2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 0.3552 on 148 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.8172,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.816 
> F-statistic: 661.6 on 1 and 148 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
> ```

Comment: Thanks! That really helps! Quick question, what if some of the interactions between the quadratic and cubic terms are with factor/categorical variables? Should I still use I()?

Comment: @ieaggie You're very welcome. Yea, if you mean like this `Species:I(Petal.Length^2)` it works fine. Of course, you can't take a power or other transformation of a factor level though, as that would not make any sense. But if you mean the numeric variable you're interacting it with, then yes.